# how to get the angle of arc ??

Tags: trigonometry, algorithms, circles, coordinate-systems, slope

dart game board is divided into sectors by 30 degrees like pizza slice. the given is (x, y) coordinates, and I need to find where coordinates are lying on. how can I get the angle just with coordinates???? should I use trigonometric function??? how??? or can I transform the slope of line into the angle???

I searched through google, but cannot find the answer. Sorry for beginner's question.

Comment: Which $(x,y)$ coordinates are given? What do you mean by "where they are lying on"? Which angle do you want to get?

Comment: the dart board is divided like pizza slice(please forgive my poor expression). the coordinates are (0, 55) (-77, 88), and I should find which slice the coordinate are lying on.

Comment: But these are the coordinates of what? And what do you need to find?

Comment: @GoodDeeds if $\rho$ and $\theta$ are the polar coordinates of the point $\left(x,y\right)$, the OP clearly wants the angle $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you have a coordinate system with origin at the center of the circle, x-axis horizontal, and y-axis vertical, then $x= r cos(\theta)$ and $y= r sin(\theta)$ where r is the straight line distance from the center of the circle to the point (x, y) and $\theta$ is the angle the line from the center of the circle to the point makes with the horizontal.

Comment: wow!!!!!! thank you!!! that' what I wanted